# DotLessClientOnly vs DotLess nuget package

Tags: less, dotless

I can't seem to find any info on the DotLessClientOnly nuget package. How is it different from the dotless package? Why would I want to use that over the normal dotless package? I want to use the dotless compiler to compile my less into css as part of a build task, but I can't get dotless to work without using the dotlessClientOnly...can they both be used?

Answer (score 2):

Dotless client only does not contain any of the ASP server code. It is compiled against the client profile of .NET so it can be used in non server applications.

If you want it to run as part of your build task you can use the compiler executable from either package.